# Opentelemetry python

Tags: open-telemetry

HP ENVY 17" i7 laptop:
Kubuntu 21.10

Greetings, I'm relatively new to Opentelemetry. I've followed many tutorials including opentelemetry.io but I keep running into dependency problems with the python stack.

**What is the expected behavior?**
I don't expect any error

**What is the actual behavior?**

```
python ./metrics01.py                                                                                                                                                                                                      ─╯
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iomari/temp/opentelemetry/newsample/./metrics01.py", line 7, in <module>
    from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export.controller import PushController
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export.controller'
```

**Additional context:**

Using opentelemetry-python 1.12.0rc1:

```
─ pip freeze                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ─╯
asttokens==2.0.5
backcall==0.2.0
backoff==1.11.1
certifi==2022.6.15
chainmap==1.0.3
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
colorama==0.4.5
combomethod==1.0.12
decorator==5.1.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
executing==0.8.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.3b1
grpcio==1.47.0rc1
idna==3.3
ipython==8.4.0
jedi==0.18.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
nulltype==2.3.1
opentelemetry-api==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-distro==0.31b0
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-proto-grpc==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-thrift==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-exporter-prometheus==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.31b0
opentelemetry-propagator-b3==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-propagator-jaeger==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-proto==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-sdk==1.12.0rc1
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.31b0
options==1.4.10
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.14.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.29
protobuf==3.20.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
Pygments==2.12.0
requests==2.28.0
six==1.12.0
stack-data==0.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
thrift==0.16.0
traitlets==5.3.0
typing_extensions==4.2.0
urllib3==1.26.9
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Did a pip cache purge, reinstalled all modules and all is working.